# Which one is an LL(2) but not an LL(1)

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I'm pretty sure b and d are ll2 and not one but not 100% sure.

(a) S → aaScc | aaBbc | aaBbb | aBb | ac | Ʌ
B → aBb | Ʌ

(b) S → aaScc | aaBbc | aBb | ac | Ʌ
B → aBb | Ʌ

(c) S → aaScc | aaBbc | B | ac | Ʌ
B → aBb | Ʌ

(d) S → aaScc | aaBbc | B | ac
B → aBb | Ʌ

Answer (score 1):

Prove that you always know what rule to apply if you know the next two symbols. Then show a sentence where knowing only the next symbol doesn’t determine the next rule.